# Light Weight Transactions (LWT) failing while new nodes join cluster

Tags: cassandra, datastax, datastax-java-driver, paxos, nosql

I had a 9 node cluster running Cassandra 2.0.12 (DataStax Community edition). I had to expand this cluster so added 3 more nodes following the DataStax advised as per http://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/operations/ops_add_node_to_cluster_t.html

Our application makes use of Light Weight Transaction feature and we found that while new nodes were in the JOINING state (data being streamed to them from old nodes) most of the application calls involving LWT were failing with following error

com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.UnavailableException: Not enough replica available for query at consistency SERIAL (6 required but only 5 alive)

I am not sure about

1. Why the error message says its needs 6 nodes when my replication factor is 3. Does that mean while data is being streamed from old to new nodes for the ranges that now are owned by new nodes, PAXOS will require both old and new nodes to be involved in various PAXOS stages?
2. My understanding is that while new nodes are JOINING the cluster, old nodes still get all the client requests (for the token ranges that are now owned by new nodes) but old node will forward all the WRITE requests to new nodes while still serving READ requests. How does that works with LWT and Paxos as CAS operation means both READ and WRITE. So could this be the reason why it needs 6 nodes response when doing any CAS (IF NOT EXISTS) operation. Even if that is the case, why most of the CAS operations are failing? Is there a possibly of bug in LWT while new nodes are JOINING or is it the fact that new nodes are very busy and are not responding. In my case I am sure that new nodes were not extremely busy all the time while they were in JOINING state, though LWT calls failed almost entire time while they were in JOINING state.

As soon as two out of 3 new nodes joined the cluster, we could see number of errors reduced a lot and once 3rd also joined (it took about 5 hours for 1st node to join and then others followed in next 10-20 minutes), all the errors were gone and our application was back to normal.

Can someone please explain this behavior and what if anything we could do to avoid these errors when we actually upgrade our 'production environment' (the above tests were done in our test environments).

Answer (score 0):

This is actually the intended behaviour. See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-8346

Solution: join nodes sequentially (one at a time)

Comment: @dwivedialok let me know if you run into this issue also: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-10423

Comment: yes it seems I am seeing the same issue - issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-10423